# django-filter: merge 2 models in one filter

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I use http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html  and have 2 models with the same field names, and i need one filter form for both models (not separate filter forms for models, because for 2 fields it will became 4 form fields with same names)

```
class VkwallpostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_created = django_filters.DateFilter(lookup_type='gte', label='Дата публикации', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], initial=date.today)
    class Meta:
        model = Vkwallpost
        fields = ['project', 'date_created']

class FbpagepostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_created = django_filters.DateFilter(lookup_type='gte', label='Дата публикации', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], initial=date.today)
    class Meta:
        model = Fbpagepost
        fields = ['project', 'date_created']
```

I now cannot configure view to get merged querysets for models:

```
def wallpost_list(request):
    vk = VkwallpostFilter(request.GET, queryset=Vkwallpost.objects.all())
    fb = FbpagepostFilter(request.GET, queryset=Fbpagepost.objects.all())
    items = list(vk) + list(fb)
    items.sort(key=lambda i: i.date_created, reverse=True)
    return render_to_response('vk_list.html', {'filter': items})
```

As you can see I can merge 2 models into one list and pass to template as 'filter', BUT in template in this case entire form disappears! By the way filtering is working.
I guess why it disappears - because it doesn't know what class to choose in filter.

So i need merge 2 models in one filter

Comment: @Hybrid yes, of course, i got an error 'unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'VkwallpostFilter' and 'FbpagepostFilter'' i think thats because VkwallpostFilter is not queryset, it's a filter class. Tried also merge in queryset=Vkwallpost.objects.all() but also no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix that myself, but without django-filter module, full code below. 
The key is to use standard django view that display form (can be found in docs) and after form logic i have added code responsible to show list of posts (started from row **criteria = {}**)

The crucial part is to pass dict of url arguments to both querysets for 2 models, and depending on the url parameter '**source**' choose what to show in postlist:

```
if source == 'vk':
    items = list(vkposts)
elif source == 'fb':
    items = list(fbposts)
else:
    items = list(vkposts) + list(fbposts)
```

So full view:

```
def wallpost_list(request, page_number=1):
    success = False
    project = ''
    date_created = ''
    text = ''
    source = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        postfilter_form = PostfilterForm(request.POST)
        if postfilter_form.is_valid():
            success = True
            project = postfilter_form.cleaned_data['project']
            date_created = postfilter_form.cleaned_data['date_created']
            #text = postfilter_form.cleaned_data['text']
            return redirect('posts/?project=%s&date_created=%s' % (project, date_created))
    else:
        postfilter_form = PostfilterForm(initial={'project':request.GET.get('project', '3'), 'date_created':request.GET.get('date_created', '3'),})

    criteria = {}
    last_date = date(2017, 12, 31)
    if 'author' in request.GET:
        criteria['from_id'] = int(request.GET['author'])
        success = True
    if 'likes' in request.GET:
        criteria['likes.count'] = int(equest.GET['likes'])  # {'$in': [int(sex) for sex in request.GET.getlist('sex')]}#int(request.GET['sex'])  #/?group=20548110&sex=1&sex=2   # This will return [1,2]
        success = True
    if 'comments' in request.GET:
        criteria['comments.count'] = int(request.GET['comments'])  # {'$elemMatch': {'artist': request.GET['music_artist']}}
        success = True
    if 'project' in request.GET:
        #project = Userproject.objects.get(name=self.request.GET['project'])
        criteria['project__name'] = request.GET['project']
        success = True
    if 'sentiment' in request.GET:
        criteria['sentiment'] = request.GET['sentiment']  # {'$elemMatch': {'artist': request.GET['music_artist']}}
        success = True
    if 'date_saved' in request.GET:
        criteria['date_saved__range'] = (parse(request.GET['date_saved']).date(), last_date)  # 'date': {'$gte': int(time.mktime(date_saved.timetuple()))}
        success = True
    if 'date_created' in request.GET:
        criteria['date_created__range'] = (parse(request.GET['date_created']).date(), last_date)  # 'date': {'$gte': int(time.mktime(date_saved.timetuple()))}
        success = True
    if 'source' in request.GET:
        source = request.GET['source'] 
        success = True         
    print(criteria)    

    vkposts = Vkwallpost.objects.filter(**criteria).order_by("-date_created")#[:5]
    fbposts = Fbpagepost.objects.filter(**criteria).order_by("-date_created")#[:5]
    if source == 'vk':
        items = list(vkposts)
    elif source == 'fb':
        items = list(fbposts)
    else:
        items = list(vkposts) + list(fbposts)
    items.sort(key=lambda i: i.date_created, reverse=True)
    post_list = items
    current_page = Paginator(post_list, 20)
    # context['post_list'] = items # post_list это VK + FB posts
    # vk = VkwallpostFilter(request.GET, queryset=Vkwallpost.objects.all())
    # fb = FbpagepostFilter(request.GET, queryset=Fbpagepost.objects.all())
    # items = list(vk) + list(fb)
    # items.sort(key=lambda i: i.date_created, reverse=True)
    return render_to_response('vk_list.html', {'post_list': current_page.page(page_number), 'postfilter_form': postfilter_form,
                                               'project': project, 'date_created': date_created, 'source': source, 'text': text, 'success': success}
                              , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your github post :)

You can do vk.qs and fb.qs to get the filtered QuerySets. Then in you context you need vk and/or fb, because they are responsible for the form.

Comment: Could you provide full code? In context i need merged filter, not separated for vk and fb, imagine i would have separated, then for 2 fileds my user need input in 2x filters = 4

Comment: Just use one form, which creates get parameters like:  ?date_created=2015-12-24. This will automatically filter both filters.

Comment: @ i think this is misunderstading between us) i pointed out in question that if i use one form for 2 qs i see no for at all. I was able to fix that myself, but without django-filter module